# what does "甘えるって" mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning, spelling

甘 is sweet right?
甘えるって is to be sweet or does it mean something completely different?

Comment: You could look it up in a dictionary to find the answer.

Comment: https://jisho.org/search/甘える

Comment: Your question is difficult to answer without more context.

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Generally, it has a negative connotation (to be spoiled, to fawn over). This might help: http://www.gabastyle.com/english/naruhodo/naruhodo417/